# Как ускорить вывод текста в командную строку Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь сделать что-то в виде анимации в консоли.

Столкнулся с проблемой: python медленно выводит текст в консоль, что приводит к мерцанию и сильному разрыву картинки. Видно, что текст выводится строчка за строчкой.

В [данном видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4zUgtDk95w) *Onigiri* столкнулся с такой же проблемой (12:05).
В видео сказано, что в C++ есть функция, которая прямо устанавливает значение символов, которые должны быть в консоли (12:34).

Есть ли что-то подобное в python, и, в принципе, возможно ли выводить текст быстрее/сразу, дабы не было мерцания.

Comment: покажи код, скажу где поправить

Comment: Нет, такие функции мне неизвестны разве что поможет библиотека windows-curses

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать две отдельные функции как сделал я. В одной создается массив, лучше использовать numpy, а во второй следуя по массиву создаются строка. Первую можно ускорить с помощью numba, а со второй не выйдет, так как numba не умеет работать со строками, если не прав, буду только рад узнать. Медленность кода не в выводе в консоль, там все в порядке, а в создании листа. Такими костылями у меня все хорошо заработало. Видимо ответ тебе поздно пришел))

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Какое отношение numpy и numba имеют к анимации в консоли?

Comment: К консоли никакого, но ускорит весь код очень хорошо, знаю, потому что сам делал тоже самое, из того же самого видео. Голый питон даже близко не был похож на желаемый результат